# Animation Stickman

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

In my app I have a stickman, which moves to right when you click a button. Within that time (moving to the right) I want to animate 6 pictures, where you see the stickman running. The purpose of clicking that button is to do it as fast as possible, and I want to let the stickman finish running even when the user clicks the button again. It's a kind of a race to get at the finish as fast as possible. My purpose is to make the running of the stickman look natural, so the running doesn't start again when the stickman is not yet ready with his steps.

Is there anyway to do this??

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: You'll probably need more frames then 6 to make it smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be very straight forward, just define a (global) variable or a class property that like `status` that you can set it to `running` or `stopped` and when the button is clicked check `if (status!=running)`

Does this solve your problem?
If you show us some code and point out the exact problem people could better help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

say have an

> UIImageView *imView1;
>
> NSTimer *timer1;
>
> count = 1;

say images have name as

img1,img2,...,img6 - PNGs.

inside the timer method:
{

> count++;
>       [imView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d.png",count]]];
>       if(count==6) count = 0;

}

If you want to increase or decrease the speed, you can change the time interval. The loop will not break.